# How to create this type of layout using coordinatorLayout , AppbarLayout ,CollaspingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

Anyone please guide me how to make this type of layout i have tiny knowledge about this.

it has

1> FloatingActionButton

2> 1 ImageView usging in CollapsingToolbarLayout to parallex

3>1 TabLayout with ViewPager

I am not able to create middle layer of layout in which 2nd ImageView and its relevant text and FloatingButton  anchored.

[here is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFHoS.gif)
    <

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.express.entertain.profileapp.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/poster"
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```